# Drupal update domain whitelist

Tags: updating

I'm working on a Drupal project that will live on a locked-down webserver. The internet access on that box is constrained by a domain whitelist so I need to be able to provide a complete list of the domains that are needed for Drupal to update itself and its modules.

We're using Acquia-Drupal so we'll certainly the following to be able to update Drupal itself:

```
git.acquia.com
```

I ran a drush update while listening with `netstat -t -u -c` to try and get a feel for which domains are needed. This raised the following:

```
*.drupal.org  (obviously)
ec2-174-129-202-133
```

The latter seems to be an AWS domain.

I realise it may depend on the modules to some extent, but is there a definitive (and unchanging) list of domains that are required to update Drupal's modules?

I'm particularly concerned that if I start getting into AWS domains, they will change down the line, breaking our update path!

Comment: @kiamlaluno Why edit out my thanks to people for taking the time to read (and hopefully answer) my question?! Stack Exchange sites are all about their communities and speaking in a friendly and approachable way makes everyone's time here more pleasant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whitelist that we used (which seems to work fine) is as follows:

```
master.drupal.org
master2.drupal.org
ftp.drupal.org
ftp-osl.osuosl.org
git.acquia.com  <-- we are using this repo for Drupal core, you may not need it
```

They may not all be needed, `ftp-osl.osuosl.org` in particular may be required by another part of our stack, but this represents a working list of required domains.